# Windows 7 - Reboot necessary when connecting a new monitor?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I am using a graphic card with two DVI outputs and wonder about the following:
After Windows 7 is started can I connect a new monitor over DVI without doing a reboot? It doesn't work right now, using a Matrox graphic card, but I want to know if it should work in general.

Addition: It's not a laptop or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should work without a reboot

Thought I'd better add a proviso:
some graphics cards will switch off an output if no monitor is found at power up. It's not a Windows function and should be able to be overridden by using the graphics manufacturer's control software to re-detect monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Usually.  I have had somewhat mixed success myself with this.  Most of the time, when a second monitor is attached, a simple power cycle off and on of the monitor will get Windows to spot it and start it up if it isn't recognized immediately when plugged in.  However, sometimes I have had to do a full reboot to get it to recognize.

However, I should also note in the interest of completeness that it is generally considered not a good idea to plug and unplug monitors while your PC is powered on.  Monitor plugs are not considered "hot swapable" like USB or Firewire or Ethernet would be.  While the potential is very small, there is the potential of power surges or static discharge which could potentially damage your video card.  I've never had this problem nor had it happen to friends, but the potential is there.

Comment: I just plugged a DVI-to-HDMI cable into port 2 on my video card, running to my tv, and my system spontaneously rebooted. Never had that happen before, and I thought that the risk you describe only applied to VGA connections, but there ya go.